# Does increasing aptitude per level make a difference?

Tags: disgaea-5

Is there any difference if I max out the equipment aptitude by stage (starting from demon, to demon lord, to overlord, to super overlord) compared to maxing out said equipment aptitude if I started at a higher level (e.g. started at super overlord)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aptitudes will increase by the same amount from being promoted as if you'd made a new character in the next tier, so that won't make a difference in the end. However, you won't have higher *base* stats like a character that started at a higher tier, so a character promoted from tier 1 to 6 will be weaker than a new character you started at tier 6. This is explained in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72615424/833354806):

> When Promoting automatically, a character gets their Aptitudes increased to match the new tier, but their base stats aren't recalculated, and base stats factor into stat growths, so a character that started at Tier 6 will be stronger than a character that started at Tier 1 and ranked up to Tier 6.

Comment: I meant when in chara world. After the goal, you can choose a prize in which one of them is to increase equipment aptitude.

Comment: @Phoenix right. Promoting a character will increase their aptitudes by a set amount which doesn't change even if you've increased it via the chara world. It makes no difference if you've been promoting one character vs making a new one. The real difference is in the character's base stats, which will always be higher for a character that started at a higher tier than one you've promoted from a lower tier.